# Python aiohttp request return 401

Tags: python, authentication, aiohttp

The response.status always returns 401.
What's the problem?
Through the browser authentication is successful

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def f():
    async with aiohttp.request('GET', "http://{}/".format("10.80.7.192"), auth=aiohttp.BasicAuth('root','root') ) as response:
        return response.status



ioloop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [ioloop.create_task(f())]
wait_tasks = asyncio.wait(tasks)
done, set = ioloop.run_until_complete(wait_tasks)

for future in done:
    value = future.result()
    print(value)

ioloop.close()
```

Comment: Your code looks OK; are you sure the browser uses Basic Auth? Also, compare the request headers (browser vs aiohttp)  because the server might check those.

Comment: could you check the response body as well? Might be useful